# Create object Date from string with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

In PHP if i have:

```
$date = "2012-01-18 16:00";
```

I can do:

```
$newDate = new DateTime($date);
```

In JS (jQuery) i have:

```
var date = "2012-01-18 16:00";
```

why i can't:

```
var newDate = new Date(date);
```

? This return me Invalid date.

Comment: `var date = "2012-01-18 16:00"; console.log(new Date(date));`
works fine for me, where are you instituting this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for that string to be [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), you need a T between the date and the time

```
var date = "2012-01-18T16:00";
var newDate = new Date(date);
```

so to fix your original code:

```
var date = "2012-01-18 16:00";
date = date.replace(" ", "T");
var newDate = new Date(date);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrRqL/)

---

The Date constructor will also take a year, month, and day

```
var newDate = new Date(2012, 1, 18)
```

though to get that to work you'd have to split your string up.

Comment: I receive string - "2012-01-18 16:00". How can i make this? What i must use for this?

Comment: very thanks. And how can i use length? newDate.getMinutes().length return me undefinded. thanks for help

Comment: @MarkFondy - get minutes returns an integer.  I don't think there's a length property on a JavaScript integer

Comment: so how can i check length? i must use this, because getMinutes return me 0-9 instead of 00-09. Maybe can return 00-59 minutes instead of 0-59?

Answer (score 1):

You (almost) can:

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ]);
```

Even better, include [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and do this:

```
Date.parse("2012-01-18 16:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) is an open-source Javascript Date library that is able to recognize many date input formats, including the one that you supplied in your question. It also works within the local time zone. 
If you don't want to use that library, you can still simply replace the space in your date string with a T, as such:

```
var date = "2012-01-18 16:00";
var newDate = new Date(date.replace(" ","T"));
```

Note that this method assumes that your input is in GMT and will subtract or add the appropriate number of hours for the local user, whereas Datejs won't.

Comment: Also, it's better practice to combine multiple var statements into one: `var date = "2012-01-18 16:00", newDate = new Date(date.replace(" ","T"));`